# Grails 2.4 joda-time plugin

Tags: java, grails, jodatime

I am trying to add JodaTime plugin into my Grails application but it's giving error. I added plugins into BuildConfig like

```
 plugins {
    compile ":joda-time:1.9"
 }
```

After downloading it's giving error.

[image: **Error Snap**]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Group id:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time
compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9'
```

In maven repo is no no Version 1.9 available. Think you mean 2.9

Comment: so where I have to add your Group id ? its inside plugin or dependency ?

Comment: In front of the first `:` so your string must Looks like `"joda-time:joda-time:2.9"`

Comment: can you Show the string again?

Comment: compile ":joda-time:joda-time:2.9"

Comment: remove the first `:`